# How to initialize sbyte* in c#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am building a c# application, in my application, I load a c++/cli dll, and calling its function.

I have declare a value class in my c++/cli class.

```
public value class S_OpenParam {
        public :
          int iPort;
          char* szIpAddress;
          int iBaudRate;
};
```

Then , I am trying to initialize my S_OpenParam in my c# application.

I am facing problem on initialize the **char* szIpAddress**

```
myObj.S_OpenParam sParam;
sParam.iBaudRate = 0;
sParam.iPort = 0;
```

When I try to assign a value to it:

```
sParam.szIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
```

It shows the type is sbyte*

[image]

Do you know how to initialize it ?

Comment: whats the acutal type of szIpAddress in c#? I mean, what is it expecting?

Comment: Just don't do that!  C# is a thoroughly modern language, it gives you no easy rope to hang yourself with these ancient 8-bit encodings.  Anything declared `public` must use `String^` instead of `char*`.  It is up to your C++/CLI code, if necessary, to convert that System::String to a legacy encoding.  Not making that necessary is easy too, encoding an IP address in an 8-bit string is something you had to do 25 years ago.  We're in the 21st century today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a C++/CLI dll, why don't you use String^ instead of char*, so that you will be able to update it from c# without problems ?

```
public value class S_OpenParam {
        public :
          int iPort;
          String^ szIpAddress; <-- String^ instead of char*
          int iBaudRate;
};
```